# Amazon Quicksight - How do I show two different filters of the same data on the same line graph?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

In Amazon Quicksight, I have a dataset with a bunch of data items which are imported into SPICE from JSON in S3. For simplicity, assume that data items look like this:

`{url: "/us/page1.html", errors: 6, Responsetime: "2021-03-21T10:00:01"}`

There are many data items for the same URL, run on different test dates (the `Responsetime`).

I can create a graph, a "visual", of total errors over time for all urls by making a line chart with value `sum(errors)` and X dimension of `Responsetime`, and that works fine.

I can create the same visual showing total errors over time *but only for URLs matching `/us/`* by creating a custom filter for `url` matching `contains` `/us/` and applying this filter to the visual, and this also works fine and looks like this:

[image: the graph for errors over time, only for error data with URL matching /us/]

I can create the same visual showing total errors over time *but only for URLs matching `/blog/`* by creating a custom filter for `contains` `/blog/` identically to the above but with a diferent filter, and this *also* works fine and looks like this:

[image: the graph for errors over time, only for error data with URL matching /blog/]

What I want to do is display those last two graphs as two lines on the *same* graph. So I have one linechart with two values on it, where one value is field `errors` filtered by `url contains /us/`, and the second value is field `errors` filtered by `url contains /blog/`. That is, something like this:

[image: the graph for errors over time, showing error data with URL matching /us/ and error data with URL matching /blog/ as two separate lines]

How do I do this?

I know how to plot two *different* values on the same linechart, but not how to plot the same value but filtered in two different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a calculated field like `url_type` and pass the formula to know what type of url is it

```
ifelse(locate({url}, "/us/") > 0, "us",locate({url}, "/blog/") > 0, "blog", "other")
```

and add this calculated field to the color of the line chart. This will divide the same dataset into two parts.

The `url_type` field will have "other" value as well, you can add a filter if that's not needed.